# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT() Treat First Value Differently Than Others

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I'm struggling to create a "path" of items in a `GROUP_CONCAT()` select without thinking of using a `MIN()` which I know I can't do.

## Sample Data

- `ID`: `[1, 1, 1, 2, 2]`
- `Number`: `[1, 2, 3, 2, 3]`
- `Leg`   : `[A-B, B-C, C-D, E-G, G-Z]`

I'd like to have results like this for `ID`'s `1` and `2`:

- **`ID`**, **`Path`**
- `1`, `A-B-C-D`
- `2`, `E-G-Z`

and I'm currently using the following `GROUP_CONCAT()`

```
SELECT ID, GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN Number = 1 THEN Leg ELSE RIGHT(Leg, 1) END SEPARATOR '-') 
Path FROM my_table GROUP BY ID;
```

but this doesn't work when the `Number` column for an `ID` doesn't start at 1. I'd ideally like to start it at the `MIN()` of the `Number` within and `ID` but I can't do that. Is there anyway to conditionally do it on the first value in the `GROUP_CONCAT()`?

Comment: You need windowing functions, which are available in MySQL 8.0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT ID,
       CONCAT_WS('-',
                 SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(LEFT(Leg, 1) ORDER BY NUMBER), ',', 1),
                 GROUP_CONCAT(RIGHT(Leg, 1) ORDER BY NUMBER SEPARATOR '-') 
                )
FROM my_table
GROUP BY id;
```

Note:  Your query should have the separator in it as well.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to solve using a groupwise minimum as well.